# How to make categorical variables binary in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Basically, I'm new to R, and have a dataset where there are a few categorical variables. However, these are not defined by 1 or 0 or anything numerical, for example, gender is categorized into male or female, not 1 or 0.

How can I change all the male to be 1 and female to be 0? Seems as though my mutate and case when functions aren't working as a result of how the variables are presented.

Thanks!

Tried to use mutate functions to get regression analysis on each of the variables, such as how well male students performed on examination compared to female, etc, but mutate functions always showed up saying "unexpected symbol". Wondering what this means.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways how you can achieve what you want. Here are some examples:

```
library(dplyr)
# conditial
df %>% 
  mutate(gender_binary = case_when(
    gender == "male" ~ 1,
    gender == "female" ~ 0,
    TRUE ~ NA_real_  
  ))

# factoring
df %>% 
  mutate(
    gender_factor = factor(gender, levels = c("female", "male")), # here female is 1 and male is 2
    gender_binary = as.numeric(gender_factor) - 1  # Subtract 1 to align with your encoding, here female = 0 male = 1
  )

# package version specifically for creating dummy variables

#install.packages("fastDummies")
library(fastDummies)

dummy_cols(df, select_columns = "gender")
```